# TesseractApi Xamarin Infinite Freeze

Tags: xamarin.forms, tesseract

I am using Tessaract's Xamarin Forms Nuget(https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin), and am trying to scan a picture taken by the Android Device. This is the code that I am using:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> OCRAsync(byte[] bytes)
    {
        TesseractApi api;
        api = new TesseractApi(this, AssetsDeployment.OncePerInitialization);

        await api.Init("bul");
        await api.SetImage(bytes);

        var detectedText = api.Results(PageIteratorLevel.Block);

        result = string.Empty;

        if (detectedText != null)
        {
            foreach (var annotation in detectedText)
            {
                    result = FindWordInDictionary(annotation.Text);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The method is called from a synchronized method like this:

```
var task = OCRAsync(data);
result = task.Result;
```

Whenever the compiler gets to "await api.Init("bul");" the app freezes indefinitely. Do you know what may cause this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to give a file location in the .init function:

```
await api.Init(pathToDataFile, "bul");
```